# Elixir Task - Graceful shutdown

Tags: elixir, task, shutdown

I have Elixir Task, which takes some time (10 seconds). When the application is upgrading, this task is killed by `Task.Supervisor` despite on `shutdown: 30000`:

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 13-Aug-2015::00:03:09 ===
 Supervisor: {local,tasks_sup}
 Context:    child_terminated
 Reason:     killed
 Offender:   [{pid,<0.304.0>},
              {id,'Elixir.Task.Supervised'},
              {mfargs,{'Elixir.Task.Supervised',start_link,undefined}},
              {restart_type,temporary},
              {shutdown,30000},
              {child_type,worker}]
```

I don't know how to gracefully stop the task (wait until task is complete) on application upgrade. Here is the code describing my problem:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  use Application

  def start(_, _) do
    MyApp.Supervisor.start_link([])
  end

end

defmodule MyApp.Supervisor do

  use Supervisor

  def start_link(state) do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, state, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(state) do
    children = [
      supervisor(Task.Supervisor, [[name: :tasks_sup, shutdown: 30000]]),
      worker(MyApp.Worker, [state], restart: :permanent)
    ]

    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

end

defmodule MyApp.Worker do

  def start_link(state) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, state, [name: MyApp.Worker])
  end

  def init(state) do
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_call(:which_children, _, state) do
    children = [{Task.Supervisor, :tasks_sup, :supervisor, [Task.Supervisor]}]
    {:reply, children, state}
  end

  def handle_info({:task, data}, state) do
    Task.Supervisor.async(:tasks_sup, MyApp.TaskRunner, :perform, [data])
  end

  def handle_info(_, state) do
    {:noreply, state}
  end

end

defmodule MyApp.TaskRunner do

  def perform(data) do
    # some 10 secs job
  end

end
```

Is there any thoughts or assumptions how to wait until `MyApp.TaskRunner.perform` finishes and then allow to stop the task?

It doesn't matter for me how to process tasks: using native Elixir's `Task` or via own some TaskProcessor module.

`Task.Supervisor.async` links tasks to caller, which might be a problem. However, I tried several times different cases with `async` and `start_link` and each time got the same result. My latest test was:

```
children = [
  supervisor(Task.Supervisor, [[name: :tasks_sup, shutdown: 30000]]),
  worker(MyApp.Worker, [state], restart: :permanent)
]

supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
```

and

```
Task.Supervisor.start_child(:tasks_sup, MyApp.TaskRunner, :perform, [data])
```

The worker was killed after about 2-3 secs.

Answer (score 1):

The links may be the ones bringing your tasks down. Because the worker calls `Task.Supervisor.async`, it will link the task to your worker. The worker has a timeout of 5000 miliseconds, so it will be shutdown before the supervisor, killing the tasks. You can confirm this by setting the earlier reports.

Btw, you should only call `async` if you are calling `await` later by the same process and it doesn't seem to be the case here. You should likely call `Task.Supervisor.start_child` instead (so the tasks are not linked to the caller).

Another possible reason your functions are getting killed is that the VM only keeps the latest two code module versions. If you upgrade twice in a short-interval, the old versions will be purged and their running processes killed.